# Cannot connect to my aws ec2 instance t2.medium

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I have a running aws ec2 instance (id i-0d85d54ff74277b1e), a t2.medium .

Used to connect to it from several macs (via ssh) and several windows machines (via putty), from several different places. My security group admits pretty much any inbound anything (http://prntscr.com/m3598u).

It used to work fine for several days, I did not change anything, and suddenly I cannot connect from anywhere.

I tried rebooting the instance, and even stopping it and starting it again, but to no avail.

Any tips?

Comment: Are you sure the instance's IP address didn't change?

Comment: You can use Actions / Instance Settings / Get System Log to view detailed bootup information on Linux instances. That might give you a hint as to what is happening.

Comment: The instance's IP changed -.-Thank you very much @MarkB.
Please Add an answer so I can upvote it =)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The instance's public IP probably changed. If it hadn't before, it definitely did after you stopped and restarted it.